# exceptions when loading the checkpoint of a PyTorch NN model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, checkpoint

when calling the function defined in the following cell, an exception is thrown '*TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 9 were given '* 
This [document](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AstWh2CO-HmwiQ8DNDuLrm_OOZdT?e=KVtAln) provides further detail

```
def load_checkpoint(chkptJP):
checkpoint = torch.load(chkptJP)
model2 = model1(checkpoint['input_size'],
              checkpoint['output_size'],
              checkpoint['fc1'],
              checkpoint['fc2'],
              checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'],
              checkpoint['epoch'],
              checkpoint['class_to_idx'],
              checkpoint['learning_rate'])
model2.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
return model2
```

The code that wrote out the checkpoint is as follows:

```
checkpoint ={'input_size':512,
         'output_size':102,
         'fc1':256,
         'fc2':102,
         'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
         'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
         'epoch': epoch+1,
         'class_to_idx': model.class_to_idx,
         'learning_rate': 0.003}
torch.save(checkpoint,chkptJP)
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: from the document shared I got the conclusion that you are doing transfer learning on pre-trained model with custom dataset and tweaking few layers and then checkpointing it.. is it ?

Comment: hi could you show the forward function code ?

Comment: yes, it is indeed transfer learning starting from RESNET18 which I customize by replacing & training the classifier: https://github.com/joepareti54/image-classification/blob/master/ImageClassifierRESNET-local.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates `model1` is an already instantiated network, while it should be a class. For comprehensive information see [official documentation about saving](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html)(and always refer to it when in doubt). I will link to it throughout the answer so make sure to check it out and understand what's going on.

### Saving general checkpoint

Your code saves a [general checkpoint](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#saving-loading-a-general-checkpoint-for-inference-and-or-resuming-training). You can save any dictionary this way and any information you want (it is basically [Python's pickle](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Python+pickle) and you can also tune it similarly). Yours has a lot of information, some of them are not related to the model itself.

### Loading general checkpoint

As you did, you can load all this data via `torch.load`. As you have saved `state_dict` (weights), not the whole `Model` (how it's code looks) you have to create the model a-new with random weights and load them afterwards.

This code should be fine:

```
def load_checkpoint(chkptJP):
    checkpoint = torch.load(chkptJP)
    model = ModelClass(
        checkpoint["input_size"],
        checkpoint["output_size"],
        checkpoint["fc1"],
        checkpoint["fc2"],
        checkpoint["optimizer_state_dict"],
        checkpoint["epoch"],
        checkpoint["class_to_idx"],
        checkpoint["learning_rate"],
    )
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint["state_dict"])
    return model
```

Notice **`ModelClass`** has to be class, not an object as you did here. If `model1` is an object, running `model1(arg1, ..., arg9)` will call it's `__call__` method, which in turn is a wrapped `forward` method if `model1` is an instance of `torch.nn.Module`. **`ModelClass`** should be something like this in your code (and is probably defined somewhere):

```
import torch


class ModelClass(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self,
        input_size,
        output_size,
        fc1,
        fc2,
        optimizer_state_dict,
        epoch,
        class_to_idx,
        learning_rate,
    ):
        # Your initialization code here
        ...

    def forward(tensor):
        # Your forward pass here
        ...
```

If you don't have `ModelClass` anywhere you have to save whole model separately (e.g. `torch.save(model)` instead of `torch.save(model.state_dict()))` and load it as a whole (`torch.load(PATH)` instead of `chkp=torch.load(PATH)` followed by `model.load_state_dict` called on an instance)

Comment: thank you so much; in my case, I am using resnet18 from torchvision. I can't see ModelClass anywhere

Comment: @josephpareti it is `torchvision.models.resnet18` in such case

Comment: not sure how to implement, sorry. There is a ResNet class definition here https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/resnet.py should it be included in my notebook, and how does it work given I am already using model1 = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)